# Java REST getting data from webserver using Postman

Tags: java, rest, postman

I've watched nice video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kohfw-0xc6o&t=321s how to work with rest and get data from webserver, the problem is even thou I did everything nice and understand what and why is done, I cannot connect with server. My code is:
Main app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Lab3Application {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Lab3Application, args)
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    MyCallable myCallable;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myapp")
    public String myApp() {
        System.out.println("WOWOWOW");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               System.out.println("WOWOWOW");
                String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://c3f837c7-3088-4165-a4f3-ad11b24c41f1.mock.pstmn.io", String.class);
            System.out.println(response);
        }

        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("TIME: " + (finish - start) + " ms");
        return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newApp")
    public String newApp() {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Future<String> future = executorService.submit(myCallable);
            list.add(future);
        }

        for(Future<String> f : list) {
            try { f.get(); }
            catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

        }

        executorService.shutdown();

        long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("TIME: " + (finish - start) + " ms");

        return "success";
    } 
}
```

For future:

```
@Component
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("https://c3f837c7-3088-4165-a4f3-ad11b24c41f1.mock.pstmn.io", String.class);
    }
}
```

And now in intelliJ I click 'Run' and I've got:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2019-12-09 10:53:18.614  INFO 11920 --- [           main] com.example.lab3.Lab3Application         :            Starting Lab3Application on Acer-Aspire with PID 11920 (C:\Users\kamsz\Downloads\lab3\target\classes started by kamsz in C:\Users\kamsz\Downloads\lab3)
2019-12-09 10:53:18.617  INFO 11920 --- [           main] com.example.lab3.Lab3Application No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-09 10:53:19.218  INFO 11920 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker :     Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type     [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$81724b8b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-09 10:53:19.249  INFO 11920 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-12-09 10:53:19.450  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-09 10:53:19.460  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-09 10:53:19.464  INFO 11920 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2019-12-09 10:53:19.559  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-09 10:53:19.559  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 879 ms
2019-12-09 10:53:19.719  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-12-09 10:53:20.187  INFO 11920 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  :         Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-12-09 10:53:20.187  INFO 11920 --- [           main] com.example.lab3.Lab3Application         :     Started Lab3Application in 1.926 seconds (JVM running for 3.233)
```

I've also created mock server using Postnam, so if in browser I go to: https://c3f837c7-3088-4165-a4f3-ad11b24c41f1.mock.pstmn.io/myapp I've got string {"status": "ok"} written.

My question is how to run this app to execude code in for loops (restTemplate.getObject...) becouse right now I've got just Started Application and no strings. I've iven added

```
 System.out.println("WOWOWOW");
```

in random places to check if it goes there and it doesn't. I'm new to that so please, help me run it properly so I could play with it little more and learn how to do it.

Comment: On which endpoint did you send your requests? Are you sending a GET to `http://localhost:8080/myapp` ?

Comment: I think you are missing a rest request you are trying to send (POST/GET..) on your method, add for example GetMapping(value="/myapp")  then you just send your url : www.localhost:8080/myapp  then you will get you message